# Unable to receive extras in Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

GCMIntTentService.java

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("request") != null
        && !intent.getStringExtra("request").equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("request");
        String cardNo = intent.getStringExtra("requestCardNumber");
        String amount = intent.getStringExtra("requestAmount");
        String cardHoldername = intent.getStringExtra("requestHoldername");
        // This is how to get values from the push message (data)

        long timestamp = intent.getLongExtra("timestamp", -1);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.logofinal,
                "App Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Fund_Transfer.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("request", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("requestCardNumber", cardNo);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("requestAmount", amount);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("requestHoldername", cardHoldername);

        /*
         * notificationIntent.putExtra("mobile", mob);
         * notificationIntent.putExtra("desc", desc);
         * notificationIntent.putExtra("amt", amt);
         */
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "DvPay Notification", message,
                pendingIntent);

        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        sendGCMIntent(context, message,cardNo,amount,cardHoldername);
        notificationManager.notify(0, note);
    }
}

private void sendGCMIntent(Context ctx, String message,String requestCardNumber, String requestAmount, String requestHoldername) {

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

    broadcastIntent.putExtra("request", message);

    broadcastIntent.putExtra("requestCardNumber", requestCardNumber);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("requestAmount", requestAmount);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("requestHoldername", requestHoldername);

    ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

Fund_Transfer.java

```
if(bundle.getString("request")!=null && !bundle.getString("request").equalsIgnoreCase("") && !bundle.getString("request").equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
        String message = bundle.getString("request");
        System.out.println("-------------------Notification message---------"+message);
        String tempCard = bundle.getString("requestCardNumber");
        String name = bundle.getString("requestHoldername");
        String amount = bundle.getString("requestAmount");
        edtamt.setText(amount);
        payeeName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardHolder.setText(name);
        card = tempCard;
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------"+card);
    }
```

I am sending extras from my notification in GCMIntentService class but I don't understand what the problem is. I am able to receive the String called "request" but unable to receive other strings in my fund transfer class.I have checked it in debugger the values are properly passing to Fund_Transfer class.

Comment: See [My Answer Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30705611/2715073). This question is already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got my answer this line was creating a problem for me

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
```

changed it to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```